# Stop Virtualbox exposing RDP

Tags: virtualbox

Forgive the lazy approach. I've got Virtualbox on Linux, with some Windows VMs. Unfortunately Virtualbox out of the box expose port 3389 to the Internet. Considering below, I'm a little surprised and annoyed - that should stay private (I ssh and forward ports to gain access, just for the record).

```
$ grep private_network Vagrantfile
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

After vagrant up we see of course

```
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3389 (guest) => 3389 (host) (adapter 1)
```

And right enough, from my laptop in an entirely different location:

```
$ nmap 123.11.22.33 -pT:3389|grep open
3389/tcp open ms-wbt-server
```

Yes I can block with firewall, but I really want to stop Virtualbox doing this insane thing. Grateful for suggestions.

Comment: Actually, VirtualBox isn’t what’s doing this. It’s Vagrant.

Comment: You're right. Vagrant does all this magic, and there seem to be no obvious way to just make it stop. I cannot work out how to bind it to a virtual eth0... It absolutely insists on exposing some port from the VBox.. e.g. LISTEN     0      10           0.0.0.0:2200          0.0.0.0:*     users:(("VBoxHeadless",pid=55099,fd=20))

Comment: Vagrant does what the Vagrantfile says. Checked that yet?

Comment: Yes, checked Vagrantfile, this where the grep above came from. The issue seems to be Vagrant trying to be clever and make it work no matter what. I'm trying to work out how to force it not to bind networking to all interaces. No luck yet.

Comment: First VM I can bind to 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 is not exposed. Second VM cannot, as there's now a port conflict... So maybe I can add some more loopback addresses.

Comment: At my wits end. I think it's time to drop Virtualbox.    # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11", name: 'vboxnet0', adapter: 2 ... why on earth should this expose anything... Beats me.

Comment: I think I've nailed it. I was able to add 2 vip in Linux, e.g. ip addr add 1.2.3.4/24 brd + dev eth0 label eth0:0; ip addr add 1.2.3.5/24 brd + dev eth0 label eth0:0 (forgive us the non-conformant IP range!) - and then in each Vagrantfile a corresponding to said IP address  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, id: 'rdp', guest: 3389, host: 3389, host_ip: "1.2.3.5". and config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10" ... As of now, I have two VMs up with no exposure in the wild, and I can RDP to both via ssh forwards. I will provide a fuller response later as an answer.

Comment: A single vip works just fine if we ensure the host port does not collide, this was expected of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is *an* answer, not necessarily *the* answer.... The box is running Debian 11 (bullseye). If anyone has a more elegant way, I'm all ears. The annoying thing about below is that it requires a network change on the host. I would have liked if Vagrant could have done all of it.

I've added below to /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.0.0.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  pre-up ip link add eth0 type dummy
```

And restarted the network or rebooted, so now we have a new interface.

In my Vagrantfile, I have as follows, host_ip and host being the important bit. Between Vagrantfiles, all we now need to change is the host: portnumber.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "~/box/windows10.box"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, id: 'rdp', guest: 3389, host: 33810, host_ip: "10.0.0.1"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.110"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
   vb.gui = false
  end
end
```

If you know ssh, you can now ssh into the tin, and with a LocalForward 33810 10.0.0.1:33810 in your ~/.ssh/config, you can point your RDP client to 127.0.0.1:33810.

Answer (score 0):

Windows hosts expose many ports/services to the local network and I'm assuming Linux does the same. In both cases, they're not usually exposed directly to the internet. Your problem isn't Virtualbox, but that Virtualbox is directly exposed to the internet. You state that you don't want to use a firewall, but that is in fact the correct and proper solution.

Comment: The proper solution is to not expose the port when exposure serves no purpose. A firewall is either a mitigation of poor design, or a requirement where exposure is the only viable design.